# Create default mongoDB user with access to all databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am trying to create local dev environment NodeJS (node:latest) & MongoDB on docker (mongo:latest) and I use mongoose to connect with MongoDB. I would like setup very simple environment.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
  services:
    server:
    build: .
    container_name: cms_webserver
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/api
      - ./node_modules:/app/node_modules
   links:
      - mongo
 mongo:
   container_name: cms_mongo
   image: mongo
   environment:
     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=cms
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   volumes:
     - ./docker/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
     - ./data:/data/db
 adminmongo:
   image: mrvautin/adminmongo
   ports:
     - "1234:1234"
```

mongod.conf

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
security:
    authorization: disabled
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
```

Anytime when I rebuild docker I remove content of data/. Every time I have seen like new user is added with success:

```
Successfully added user: {
   "user" : "root",
   "roles" : [
      {
        "role" : "root",
        "db" : "admin"
      }
   ]
}
```

When I try connect to mongoDB in node I use

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo')
```

and get info about success.

When I try connect to mongoDB to default DB: cms

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:root@mongo/cms')
```

I get an error:

> SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for root on cms from client
>   172.18.0.4:59142 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user root@cms

My first question is how can I disabled security? I found and an option to set `security: authorization: disabled` and even I have done with this still get problem.

Second question is in topic.

1. Run `docker ps` and check which container belongs to mongo then use `docker exec -it XXX bash` to log into. I use simple command `mongo` and I can log to mongo. What I can do is open mongo with command

`mongo -u root -proot admin` but I cannot with `mongo -u root -p admin` (mongo does not ask me about password)

2. As an admin (root/root) I can create new DB by run command `use cms`, I can also add record and check if DB exist
3. I can create new user let say: 
   `db.createUser({user:"test",pwd:"test",roles:[{role:"dbOwner",db:"cms"}]});`
4. I exit and try again log to DB `cms` I created and get an error:

> MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
>   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cms
>   MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
>   2018-04-03T12:13:41.428+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication > failed. :
>   DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
>   @(auth):6:1
>   @(auth):1:2
>   exception: login failed

Is there anyone who knows what's going on and could explain me what I am doing wrong or even give me ready to use examples how I can setup mongo DB on my local? I am not very strong in DevOps and I am totally lost.